# how to match attributes order of two instances in weka

Tags: attributes, merge, weka, instances

i have two Instances from `StringToWordVector` filter' output in this format:

```
instances1

a b c 
1 3 2 
5 6 7


instances2

b c a
8 9 1
5 7 8
```

i want to match these attribute and make a merged instances in this format :

```
a b c
1 2 3
5 6 7 
1 8 9
8 5 7
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the `InputMappedClassifier`. If you keep the original doc collection you have two other options described [here](http://jmgomezhidalgo.blogspot.com.es/2013/05/mapping-vocabulary-from-train-to-test.html).